# How execute php function while closing browser

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know this has asked before but the answer is not clear.

Here is the task i want to delete a column from a table on closing the browser not the window. i want that event to be handled on unexpected shutdown.

Is there any possible way to call a php function when i close browser.

Comment: Without JS specifically AJAX it is not possible to do. php works on server. once pages leaves server it does not know anything about it. php cant know what is going on in browser so thus it cant react on events. but clientside language like JS can. if you dont know it, start looking for it.

Comment: @user1538127 i know that genius i don't what to look for i am not so dumb. just give usefully comments only.

Comment: dont meant be rude or anything but from your question it seems to me you don't know that.

Answer (score 4):

first: you can only listen to "window-closed" events...

second:
you have to bind to body-"unload" event and call an XHR (ajax-request) to the php-site...

Comment: i'm sorry could you explain more because i'm new to website building and i don't know javascript

Comment: 1. include jQuery to your page (see jquery-website)
2. add the method posted by @Yohann
3. build a php-script in "track.php" which does what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The javascript:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:"/track.php",
    type:"POST",
    async:false, // so browser waits till xhr completed
    success:function() {
      alert("bye!");
    }


  });


});
```

In your php script you can do whatever you want like track the ip and log the hits etc....

Comment: just one ques how can i check in the next page weather it is redirected from this page i mean $_POST['???']; what i wanna give

Comment: Try these:
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:"/track.php",
    type:"POST",
    async:false, // so browser waits till xhr completed
    contentType:"application/json",
    data:{url:document.location.pathname},
    success:function() {
      alert("bye!");
    }


  });


});

In the php script you can access it via $_POST["url"]

Im not sure about any other methods which are server side rather than client side. The JS method would work well (the code above) but  server side data is more safe than fetching from client.

Comment: Try the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] value and see if you get the url you want of the requesting page